# Devstack installation error(Cypress verion, Ubuntu 14 using Vagrant and Virtual Box)

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, edx, openedx

I believe that the dev environment used here is pretty much common. I checked nfsd as shown below:

```
ps aux | grep nfsd
```

The output shows `nfsd` running.

With `vagrant up` command, however, I am getting the following error message. VM manager also shows some error messages. The `vagrant reload` command does not help either.

```
(many things happens up to this point smoothly...)
default: 8110 => 8110 (adapter 1)
default: 50070 => 50070 (adapter 1)
default: 8088 => 8088 (adapter 1)
default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...

The guest machine entered an invalid state while waiting for it
to boot. Valid states are 'starting, running'. The machine is in 
the 'poweroff' state. Please verify everything is configured
properly and try again.

If the provider you're using has a GUI that comes with it,
it is often helpful to open that and watch the machine, since 
the GUI often has more helpful error messages than Vagrant can
retrieve. For example, if you're using VirtualBox, run 
`vagrant up` while the VirtualBox GUI is open.

The primary issue for this error is that the provider you're 
using is not properly configured. This is very rarely a Vagrant 
issue.
```

I would really appreciate if you could guide me where to look into. 
Blessings

**ADDED[Error messages from VM and Screen Capture]**
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine devstack_default_1445305626768_97734.

VT-x is disabled in the BIOS for both all CPU modes (VERR_VMX_MSR_ALL_VMX_DISABLED).

Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: ConsoleWrap
Interface: IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}

[image]

(a debtor)<><

Comment: can you give more info about your host (mac/linux/windows) + your Vagrantfile ; are you using Virtualbox ?

Comment: My host is linux(Ubuntu 14.04). Vagranfile is directly generated as instructed in the doc (installing, configuring and running the open edx platform - chapter 5.5) It says,
$curl -L https://raw.github.com/edx/configuration/master/vagrant/release/Vagrantfile > Vagrantfile. 

By the way, Virtual Box Manager (GUI) shows a machine created, but power off status. I could not start it interactively either. This means that Vagrantfile created a virtual machine which is not working, somehow. Thank you for looking into the problem. 
(a debtor)<><

Comment: @YoungsupKim, have you checked your bios configurations ? looks like the `Secure Virtual Machine Mode` is `Disabled`.

Comment: Would you guide how to check bios configuration? I added some error message from VM. It says something about BIOS.

Comment: @YoungsupKim, something like this, http://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/enable-virtualization-in-the-bios/. The screen might be different depending on your BIOS. But if you go through all BIOS settings it should be easy to find the virtualization switch.